# How can I call a playbook multiple times?

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I have a main login that is as bellow:

```yaml
- name: Register
  hosts: "{{ host }}"
  tasks:
    - include_role:
        name: ROLE_NAME
      vars:
        service: "{{ service }}"
```

I want to call my main login multiple time something like bellow:

```yaml
- name: call main logic
  tasks:
  - import_playbook: 
    name: main-logic.yml
    loop:
      - host: "1"
        service: "s1"
      - host: "2"
        service: "s2"
```

I didn't find any solution for that, is it possible? HOW?

Comment: Why not just put these in an inventory file and pass that to the playbook, then it can just iterate over the hosts and select the service from the host file.

Comment: From [the module documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/import_playbook_module.html): `Files with a list of plays can only be included at the top level.  You cannot use this action inside a play. bypass_task_look: This task ignores the loop and with_ keywords`. In other words: loop on your role include.

Answer (score 1):

If you for whatever reason have to run the playbook(s) sequentially create a batch. However, if you want to execute the playbook on all hosts sequentially one after another, use *serial*. See [Setting the batch size with *serial*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_strategies.html#setting-the-batch-size-with-serial). The difference is that you'll see *PLAY RECAP* once. In the first case, you'll see *PLAY RECAP* three times.

**Create batch**

For example,

```yaml
shell> cat create_batch.yml 
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    my_batch:
      - {host: host1, service: s1}
      - {host: host2, service: s2}
      - {host: host3, service: s3}
  tasks:
    - command: which bash
      register: which_bash
    - copy:
        dest: "{{ playbook_dir }}/batch.sh"
        mode: "a+x"
        content: |
          {{ '#!' }}{{ which_bash.stdout }}
          {% for i in my_batch %}
          ansible-playbook main-logic.yml -e "host={{ i.host }}" -e "service={{ i.service }}"
          {% endfor %}
```

gives

```bash
shell> cat batch.sh 
#!/usr/bin/bash
ansible-playbook main-logic.yml -e "host=host1" -e "service=s1"
ansible-playbook main-logic.yml -e "host=host2" -e "service=s2"
ansible-playbook main-logic.yml -e "host=host3" -e "service=s3"
```

Given the project tree for testing

```bash
shell> tree .
.
├── ansible.cfg
├── batch.sh
├── create_batch.yml
├── hosts
└── main-logic.yml

0 directories, 5 files
```

```ini
shell> cat ansible.cfg
[defaults]
gathering = explicit
inventory = $PWD/hosts
roles_path = $PWD/roles
remote_tmp = ~/.ansible/tmp
retry_files_enabled = false
stdout_callback = yaml
```

```ini
shell> cat hosts
host1
host2
host3
```

```yaml
shell> cat main-logic.yml
- hosts: "{{ host }}"
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ inventory_hostname }} {{ service }}"
```

The batch gives

```yaml
shell> ./batch.sh 

PLAY [host1] **************************************************************************************

TASK [debug] **************************************************************************************
ok: [host1] => 
  msg: host1 s1

PLAY RECAP ****************************************************************************************
host1: ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   


PLAY [host2] **************************************************************************************

TASK [debug] **************************************************************************************
ok: [host2] => 
  msg: host2 s2

PLAY RECAP ****************************************************************************************
host2: ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   


PLAY [host3] **************************************************************************************

TASK [debug] **************************************************************************************
ok: [host3] => 
  msg: host3 s3

PLAY RECAP ****************************************************************************************
host3: ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

---

**Setting the batch size with serial**

Declare the below variables. For example, in *group_vars/all*

```yaml
shell> cat group_vars/all/my_batch.yml
my_batch:
  - {host: host1, service: s1}
  - {host: host2, service: s2}
  - {host: host3, service: s3}
my_batch_host_sevice: "{{ my_batch|
                          items2dict(key_name='host',
                                     value_name='service') }}"
service: "{{ my_batch_host_sevice[inventory_hostname] }}"
```

Set *`serial: 1`*. The playbook will serve the remote hosts one after another

```yaml
shell> cat main-logic.yml
- hosts: "{{ host }}"
  serial: 1
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: ansible_play_batch
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ inventory_hostname }} {{ service }}"
```

gives

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook main-logic.yml -e host='host1:host2:host3'

PLAY [host1:host2:host3] **************************************************************************

TASK [debug] **************************************************************************************
ok: [host1] => 
  ansible_play_batch:
  - host1

TASK [debug] **************************************************************************************
ok: [host1] => 
  msg: host1 s1

PLAY [host1:host2:host3] **************************************************************************

TASK [debug] **************************************************************************************
ok: [host2] => 
  ansible_play_batch:
  - host2

TASK [debug] **************************************************************************************
ok: [host2] => 
  msg: host2 s2

PLAY [host1:host2:host3] **************************************************************************

TASK [debug] **************************************************************************************
ok: [host3] => 
  ansible_play_batch:
  - host3

TASK [debug] **************************************************************************************
ok: [host3] => 
  msg: host3 s3

PLAY RECAP ****************************************************************************************
host1: ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
host2: ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
host3: ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```